# How do I figure out the value which is greater than certain threshold in a matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, for-loop, enumerate

Assume that I have a matrix:

```
a = [[4,7,2],[0,1,4],[4,5,6]]
```

And I want to get

```
b = [0, 1]
c = [[2],[0,1]]
```

- `b = [0,1]` because the inner lists of `a` at position `0` and `1` contain values that are smaller then `3`.
- `c = [[2],[0,1]]` because the `[2]` nd element of the first sublist in `b` is below 3 and `[0,1]` because the first and second element in the second sublist in `b` is below 3.

I tried :

```
for i in a:
   for o in i:
      if o < 3:
         print(i)
```

It only returns the original matrix.

How do I get `b`&`c` in python?

Comment: "Matrix b is that a[0], a[1] have a value that is smaller than 3, c is a[0][2] and a[0][0], a[0][1] is less than 3". This doesn't make the question sound clear at all

Comment: This doesn't give it in the exact form you are looking for, but depending on why you want to do this, you might be interested in `np.where(a<3)` which outputs the tuple `([0,1,1],[2,0,1])` giving all the indices where `a<3`.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverate [`enumerate(iterable[,startingvalue])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) which gives you the index *and* the value of the thing you iterate over:

```
a = [[4,7,2],[0,1,4],[4,5,6]] 

thresh = 3
b = [] # collects indexes of inner lists with values smaller then thresh
c = [] # collects indexes in the inner lists that are smaller then thresh
for idx, inner_list in enumerate(a):
    if any(value < thresh for value in inner_list):
        b.append(idx)
        c.append([])
        for idx_2, value in enumerate(inner_list):
            if value < thresh:
                c[-1].append(idx_2)

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

Output:

```
[[4, 7, 2], [0, 1, 4], [4, 5, 6]]
[0, 1]
[[2], [0, 1]]
```

Doku:

- [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)
- [any()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)